# Inheriting multiple text-decorations on a single element

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I experience the same strange issue with every major browser: an element gets styled with two `text-decoration` properties.

[image: text-decoration]

The first decoration comes from the parent element, the second one – from the element itself. Here's the [relevant HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/gmwmu/):

```
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
    <span style="text-decoration: line-through">Hello</span>
</div>
```

How to override the first declaration, not add to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is that the text decoration on the parent gets applied to the text in the child element, because the text in the child is also considered part of the text in the parent. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props) for details.

There is currently no way to cancel out the parent text decoration on the child while keeping the text flow. You could float or absolutely position the child element, or make it an inline block, but that alters the layout. If that isn't desirable, you'll have to find a way to move the parent `text-decoration` style to, say, a sibling of the child element within the parent. If there is bare text within the parent element, that means you need to wrap that in a sibling. So for example if you had this extra text:

```
<div style="text-decoration: underline">
    <span style="text-decoration: line-through">Hello</span>
    world
</div>
```

You'd need to wrap it, and move the declaration accordingly:

```
<div>
    <span style="text-decoration: line-through">Hello</span>
    <span style="text-decoration: underline">world</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally, I think this is contrary to the definition of *cascading*, but, well, will have to work around. Thanks!

Comment: @katspaugh: Yeah, text decorations are quite a strange beast...